# According to the Catholic Church, why did Jesus co-relate end of the world and passing of the generation of His time?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospel-of-matthew

At Matthew 24:34 Jesus, while referring to the signs of the end of the world says: "Truly I tell you, this generation will certainly not pass away until all these things have happened."

Does the Catholic Church have an official view on this passage?  Should the phrase "this generation will not pass" be taken literally, or does the church view it as an idiomatic construction to denote the imminent nature of an event predicted?

Comment: @curiousdannii except that this question asks for a Catholic answer, which the other one doesn't, nor does any of the answers provide.

Comment: @MattGutting Yep that's true, but this question first asks generally what it means and only asks about the CC second. A Catholic specific question would be good, but the question would need to be edited.

Comment: I agree it could be more clearly oriented to Catholicism.

Comment: Catholic version of existing question: [How do Roman Catholics reconcile the apocalyptic sayings of Jesus](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44349/how-do-roman-catholics-reconcile-the-apocalyptic-sayings-of-jesus-with-his-not-h). This is a duplicate.

Comment: I am inclined to accept the answers provided to the question asked earlier, as satisfactory.